# Entity Framework5 Code-First when change a table manual and broke the migration

Tags: entity-framework-5

I think I completely broke my migration I delete my migration folder and delete my table migration that generated in the database. why? for I read something that i have to delete those  so I dit

and now cant make it work 
I tried to use in my app_star and in a constructor in EfDbContext

Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());

this in my method OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();

i get this error using PM> Enable-Migrations-ProjectName EnableAutomaticMigrations Rhld-Force-Verbose

```
Enable-Migrations: There is no positional parameter that accepts the argument 'EnableAutomaticMigrations'.
At line: 1 Char: 1
+ Enable-Migrations-ProjectName EnableAutomaticMigrations Rhld-Force-Verbose
+ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
     + CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: PositionalParameterNotFound, Enable-Migrations
```

and using PM> Update-Database -ProjectName rhld -Verbose -Force

```
Using StartUp project 'Rhld'.
Specify the indicator '-Verbose' to see the SQL statements that are being applied to the target database.
Not found any migration configuration in assembly 'Rhld'. (In Visual Studio, you can use the command Enable-Migrations of the Package Manager Console to add a migration configuration).
```

so my question is what can I do now?, i will like to still using my database 
i tried to create the tables in another database and can't do it get the same error

Edit

my problem was that is was working fine at the begining then try to change a foreing key both the name and the table, and i can't so I begin to read and delete thing :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I end delete de database and

```
public EfDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<EfDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EfDbContext>());
}
```

in Application_Start

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EfDbContext>());
```

don't know what did the trick

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

and use this and it work

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ProjectName rhld -Force
Update-Database -ProjectName rhld -Verbose -Force
```